# chemfig package - Undefined control sequence \setchemfig

Tags: chemfig, undefined

I was trying to produce a reaction scheme with chemfig, but when I use the \setchemfig command I get the error message:

> Undefined control sequence \setchemfig

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\setchemfig{arrow angle=15}
\schemestart
  \chemfig{HO-[0]-[:-30](-[:-150]-[4]HO)(-[:30]-[0]OH)-[:-30]-OH}\arrow
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

Any help/insight is appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually have version 1.3 installed? Older version have different commands.

Comment: On my side it is working without errors. With version 1.31

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is a version problem. The command `\setchemfig` does not yet exist in your version of chemfig. Either upgrade the package (how to do that depends on your TeX environment), or use the commands of your chemfig version; try something like `\setarrowdefault{15}`. See the docs of your old version of chemfig.

Comment: @A. Finlay what is the name of your chemical structure `HO-[0]-[:-30](-[:-150]-[4]HO)(-[:30]-[0]OH)-[:-30]-OH`?

Comment: I was indeed using an older version.  I'm using TexLive and updated from 2017 to 2018, this solved the problem.  Thank you!

Comment: @Sebastiano the chemical structure is for pentaerythritol.

Comment: @A.Finlay Thank you very much. Can you add an image of your expect pentaerythritol, please?

Comment: @Sebastiano [Here you go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7V47.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because I was using an older version.  In my case this was solved by updating from TexLive 2017 to 2018.